# Как можно сократить этот код python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Как можно сократить этот код, чтобы его можно было использовать еще раз?

Мб его как-то в отдельный класс запихать в отдельном .py файле? Потому что нужно будет делать  что-то типа рассылки, а переписывать 100 раз одну и ту же функцию не хочется.

```
def main():
    base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot***/sendPoll"

    parameters = {
    "chat_id": "-829228048",
    "question" : 'Как ты себя чувствуешь?',
    "options" : json.dumps(["Хорошо", "Не очень"]),
    "is_anonymous": False,
}

    resp = requests.get(base_url, data=parameters)
    print(resp.text)
scheduler1 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler1.every(5).seconds.do(main)
```

Comment: Чтобы не делать одно и тоже действие - придуманы были циклы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно правильно пользоваться возможностью функций, а именно использовать аргументы

```
def main(base_url="https://api.telegram.org/bot***/sendPoll", chat_id="-829228048", question='Как ты себя чувствуешь?', options=("Хорошо", "Не очень"), is_anonymous=False):
    resp = requests.get(base_url, data=dict(chat_id=chat_id, question=question, options=json.dumps(options), is_anonymous=is_anonymous))
    print(resp.text)

scheduler1 = schedule.Scheduler()
scheduler1.every(5).seconds.do(main)
scheduler1.every(5).seconds.do(main, base_url="https://api.telegram.org/bot123/sendPoll")
scheduler1.every(5).seconds.do(main, chat_id="-123", is_anonymous=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно parametrs кинуть в отдельный файл (config, например) и оттуда импортировать

Answer (score -1):

в класс запихнуть и потом брать из класса

```
class param:
    parameters = {
    "chat_id": "-829228048",
    "question" : 'Как ты себя чувствуешь?',
    "options" : json.dumps(["Хорошо", "Не очень"]),
    "is_anonymous": False,
    }
def main():
    base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot***/sendPoll"

    parameters = param.parameters
```

Comment: А если мне нужно добавлять другие chat_id?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary